# Should I ALWAYS call close on a web service call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service that I am calling within a loop.

I was calling it Async as well.

Should I Close() it after each call or leave it open?

I am concerned about processing time being longer if i repeatedly Open() and Close the web service

and:
Memory build up (some where) If do not close it?

I am using C#.

This is my code:

```
   private void UploadToCloud()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (syncNewMotion)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(syncNewMotion);
                }

                for (ActiveCamIndex = 0; ActiveCamIndex < 4; ActiveCamIndex++)
                {
                    MotionFrame motion = GetNextUpload();
                    if (motion != null)
                    {
                        request.UploadMotion(motion.Frame, Shared.Alias, motion.camIndex, motion.MessageLog);  // I am call non -async here 
                        //because if I do this:
                        //request.UploadMotionAsync(motion.Frame, Shared.Alias, motion.camIndex, motion.MessageLog, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                        //I am worried about the router being overloaded.

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                request.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

and as soon as I know I got some new data I call it like this:

```
    public void SetCurrentFrame(byte[] jpegData, Int16 camIndex, byte[] messageLog, Int64 timestamp)
    {
        CurrentMotionFrame.Timestamp = timestamp;
        CurrentMotionFrame.MessageLog = messageLog;
        CurrentMotionFrame.camIndex = camIndex;
        CurrentMotionFrame.Frame = jpegData;
        switch (camIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                if (motionQueue1.Count < 160)
                {   
                    motionQueue1.Enqueue(CurrentMotionFrame);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (motionQueue2.Count < 160)
                {
                    motionQueue2.Enqueue(CurrentMotionFrame);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (motionQueue3.Count < 160)
                {
                    motionQueue3.Enqueue(CurrentMotionFrame);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (motionQueue4.Count < 160)
                {
                    motionQueue4.Enqueue(CurrentMotionFrame);
                }
                break;
        }
        NotifyNewUpload();
    }
```

and I start the loop with this:

```
Thread thUpload = new Thread(UploadToCloud);
thUpload.Start();
```

It is quite possible I am doing a whole catalogue of errors but have been working on this project for so long it is hard to take a step back from it.

Any advice/criticism will be welcome

Thanks

Comment: You may be calling a WebService but you're not Opening or Closing it. Post the details of your client-API classes and preferably the schematic code.